# unable to find valid certification path to requested target logstash

Tags: logstash

I am enabling ssl on our elk stack and I am encountering an error message when connecting logstash to elasticsearch.

`

```
enter code here`2019-08-29T13:38:43,822][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://logstash_internal:xxxxxx@elastic.local:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://logstash_internal:xxxxxx@elastic.local:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

The self signed certificate is installed in the trusted on the local machine. If you know what is causing the issue and how to resolve let me know.

my logstash config is

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["https://elastic.local:9200"]
index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
ssl => true
keystore => '\config\logstash.keystore'
keystore_password => "keystore.pass"
cacert => '\config\certs\instance.crt'
ssl_certificate_verification => true
user => "{ES_USER}" password => "{ES_PWD}"
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

}

Any assistance would be much appreciated in getting this error resolved

Comment: looks like the logstash client is not able to verify the certificate presented by ES. 3 things, make sure that ES is running on port 9200 over SSL. Second, it would be helpful to include the output of the following command `echo '' | openssl s_client -connect elastic.local:9200 1>/dev/null`. This is to verify the chain that is presented by the ES server. Third, the `instance.crt` file contents.